# Sharing ResourceDicrionary between two projects

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, app.xaml

I've an UWP app with following structure:

```
MyAwesomeApp.sln
  Common.csproj
    Resources.xaml
  Main.csproj (startup project)
    MainPage.xaml
    MainPage.xaml.cs
    App.xaml
    App.xaml.cs
  OtherProjects...
```

Can I use `Resources.xaml` in `App.xaml` or `MainPage.xaml` and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the project type of `Common`. If it's a "Class Library (Universal Windows)" or "Windows Runtime Component" project, then you could directly access the resource file like:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Common/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

If it isn't a "Class Library (Universal Windows)" or "Windows Runtime Component" project, then you can't do that.